# Is it possible to achieve the "Unachievable" achievement in "The Stanley Parable"?

Tags: achievements, the-stanley-parable

I know that according to the text it should be impossible, but global achievement statistics suggest otherwise. Is there a legitimate way to get this achievement?

[image: Unachievable]

Comment: Got this today, unsure how, was just playing the early game as normal.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes it is... But it depends on what you define as legitimate :)
Copied from this Youtube video:

> Ok, I have no idea that this is the intended way to get this achievement,
> but it works.
> Here is how:

1. Close the game!
2. Edit your config file, it is located in your Steam folder. For example:   D:\Steam\SteamApps\common\The Stanley Parable\thestanleyparable\cfg\config.cfg just open it with a text editor
3. Add this line to the file (in a new row): bind "x" "~;_u"
4. Save the file then right-click it and chose properties.
5. Check the attribute "Read-only" and save this change. This will make sure that the game won't overwrite your new key bind
6. Open the game and start a new game
7. Hit the "x" key
8. Wait a few seconds
9. Achievement Unlocked!

> Thanks to the Steam user AoM, Phone_Answerer and nairolf for this method :)

**Technical stuff:**

If you try to enter `_u` into the console, you'll get a strange error:

> Hey don't you even try

Also, if you try to enter `~;_u` in the console, you'll notice that the `~` is a forbidden char in the console. That is the reason why you need to make a key bind which executes this command.

Someone on the Steam forums also decompiled the game and found this code:

```
if ( !sub_104B22A0(v26, "map1", 4)
  && RandomInt(1, 15) == 8
  && v46
  && *LODWORD(dword_107E1B28) > (float)(*(float *)&dword_107E1898 + 20.0) )
{
  v27 = *(_DWORD *)(sub_1027BBA0() + 28);
  v28 = *(_DWORD *)dword_107E1B30;
  v41 = (int)"_u\n";
  v40 = v27;
  v39 = dword_107E1B30;
  (*(void (__cdecl **)(int, int, char[4]))(v28 + 156))(dword_107E1B30, v27, "_u\n");
}
```

So as you can see there is some kind of randomness involved `&& (RandomInt(1, 15) == 8)`

**Developer comments**

The developer also commented on this method:

> Gran PC:

> I don't really approve of reverse engineering the game and then divulging the way :/

He also posted this:

> Gran PC:

> The fun part of the achievement was having people try to work out connections really. I updated the code of the achievement every patch to account for whatever you guys discovered. Oh well, no fun allowed for developers I guess.

and this:

> Gran PC

> It's no fun if everyone knows it's *almost* random!

> In one patch I made it so quicksave & quickload would grant it, and in the next patch I made it so it was impossible to get through quickload. It was hilarious to watch people like the original poster raging :P

You can find these comments (and more) here: http://steamcommunity.com/app/221910/discussions/0/792924412213692581/#p54

I also wrote a blog article about this. It's a bit more detailed for anyone who's interested: http://www.themutegamer.com/guide/the-stanley-parable/unachievable-achievement/

Comment: Well, I'd define the way the the original creator intended as 'legitimate'. I want to see if there's some sort of confirmation from him. :)

Comment: @idan315 I'm pretty sure the way the creator indented is "never", since that is consistent with the theme of deconstructing and undermining the typical relationship between the game and the player.

Comment: Why does the command `_u` give you the achievement?  When I go to the console *(enabled by launching the game with the `-dev` parameter)* and type `_u` in the console, I get the unusual error message `Hey don't you even try`

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don't really think that the creator intended it to really be unachievable. Because why would you integrate the "_u" command into the game if you never wanted anyone to get it? It seems that this achievement is pretty random; a few users actually got it without using this method. They have no idea how though.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - I've added a few more details in my answer.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as I doubt we'll find anything even remotely as detailed, but I will be happy if you'll keep updating it as the story continues. :D

Comment: I'm sincerely hoping he finds a way to make this method not work at all.  And then to add a new achievement that is "Really Impossible" just to pour salt at those that have unlocked this one.

Comment: Apparently he did, because this method no longer does anything.