# How did I get the "Unachievable" achievement?

Tags: achievements, the-stanley-parable

I've just played through Stanley Parable for a few hours and have got all of the different endings (including all variations of the easter eggs), besides the "disco" one.

After quitting the game, I noticed that I got the "Unachievable" achievement. Looking at the time, I think that I got it around the time I got the "broken narrative" ending, but I'm not entirely sure.

I've looked up how to get the achievement and most guides involve adding key bindings and doing it through there - I definitely haven't done that. The only things I've done in the console are `sv_cheats 1` and `bark`.

---

I am not looking for **how to get** the achievement, my question is that I have got the achievement and **don't know how I did!**

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136455/is-it-possible-to-achieve-the-unachievable-achievement-in-the-stanley-parable

Comment: @Robotnik I saw that but wasn't sure how I got it as I didn't do those steps (I'd know if I had) - not sure if you're implying this is a duplicate?

Comment: How is it not?  How you got the achievement is by fulfilling the requirements for it.  Since the developer apparently delights in changing the requirements every patch, it's going to be pretty random.

Comment: @Frank The answer to the linked question gives me 9 steps involving adding new command bindings, none of which I've done. Even if the requirements are changed every step, the answer to that question is not the answer to mine, so they are not the same question :)

Comment: I would disagree with your assessment.  Mostly, how you got it, and how you're supposed to get it is just semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [read this post](https://www.themutegamer.com/guide/the-stanley-parable/unachievable-achievement/#the-actual-guide) and it will explain some back story behind it. It looks like only 1 out of 15 people unlock it without doing keybinding if they meet the criteria.

Since you mentioned that you did not do the keybindings, you must have been part of the minority who unlock it by luck!

Comment: The question actually asked how they got it, not how to get it.

Comment: Edited.  Completely misread your question!